# Qbits can be both states but how and where is the manual?

Tags: quantum-computing

So scouring the Internet attempting to find as much as i can on Quantum Computing and Qbits.

It seems perhaps even with Google's purchase of the D:Wave and the somewhat increasing speak of Quantum computing, that there is still terribly little information or references for much surrounding the concept.

I am interested in directly to understand how a Quantum Computer is constructed, the components, the logical theory and exactly how a Qbit can be a 1 or 0, or both 1 & 0 at the same time.

Comment: this is not a programming question. This is a question about quantum mechanics. Google "superposition".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because belongs on http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @PatrickGoley and yes perhaps this wasn't the correct place to post the question. Although it has some relevance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Volume 3](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_01.html) of the [Feynman Lectures on Physics](http://www.feynmanlectures.info/), one of the great Physics textbooks of the last century, is available online for free.

After you get comfortable with this, you can graduate to [Nielsen & Chuang](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107002176).

Comment: Personally I'd *start* with Nielsen & Chuang, because the physical applications are not a prerequisite for understanding qubits. YMMV.